# HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow.print() from GoogleSheets is not opening print preview

Tags: google-sheets, print-preview, printing-web-page

I am using GoogleSheets to print a png/image file using HTMLService. I created a temporary Iframe element with an img tag in the modalDialog and call IFrame element's contentWindow.print() function after IFrame element and its image are loaded. (I have not set visibility:hidden attribute of IFrame element to check if image is getting loaded.)

However, I only see the printer dialog without any print preview. I am testing on Firefox. Am I missing anything?

[Updated] - I am using Googles Apps script. performPrint() is in printJsSource.html and openUrl() is in Code.gs.

[image: window print without any preview]

```
Inside printJsSource.html

function performPrint(iframeElement, params) {
            try {
                iframeElement.focus()

                // If Edge or IE, try catch with execCommand
                if (Browser.isEdge() || Browser.isIE()) {
                    try {
                        iframeElement.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null)
                    } catch (e) {
                        iframeElement.contentWindow.print() 
                    }
                } else {
                    // Other browsers
                    iframeElement.contentWindow.print()   // as I am using Firefox, it is coming here                
                }
            } catch (error) {
                params.onError(error)
            } finally {
                //cleanUp(params)
            }
        }

Inside Code.gs

function openUrl() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("printJsSource");
  html.setWidth(500).setHeight(500);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Opening ..." );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### I think there is some general confusion about the concept

- First of all, `function performPrint()` seems to be a client-side Javascript funciton, while `function openUrl()` is a server-side [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutputFromFile(String)) function.
- While you did not specify either you use Google Apps Script - if you do so, `function openUrl()`belongs into the `code.gs` file and `function performPrint()` into `printJsSource.html` file
- `function openUrl()` allows you to open a [modal dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui?hl=en#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title) which can show some data on the UI, e.g. your image
- Do not confuse this behavior with actual printing (preview)!
- It is NOT possible to trigger the opening of a Google Sheets printing preview programamticaly!

- The Javascript method you are using [`iframeElement.contentWindow.print()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) might trigger the printing of the whole content of a browser window (different from the Google Sheets printing dialog, also [depends on the browser](https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/issues/348)), but if you try to incorporate it into the client-side coe of an Apps Script project, you will most likely run into restrictions due to the scopes of modal diloags and usage of iframes.
- While from your code it is hard to say either you implemented the funcitons in the correct files of the Apps Script project, keep in mind that to work with iframes you need to specify in `function openUrl()`

`html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am using Googles Apps script. performPrint() is in printJsSource.html and openUrl() is in Code.gs.

Comment: I am trying to print an image file by url. I create an IFrameElement inside printJsSource.html and set an img tag with src as the url inside the Iframe. The IFrame element is getting created, but Iframe.ContentWindow.print only opens the printer dialog without the preview

Comment: Which kind of preview do you expect? The Google Sheets preview? As mentioned - it is is not possible to trigger the latter programmatically, because it is a server-side feature that cannot b accessed through Javascript methods. You can file a a feature request for it on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: Print Preview of the contents of IFrameElement. I think it is the behavior of Firefox, as in Chrome, it is giving the proper preview.